# How to call a suspend function within a apply expression

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I want to call a suspend function within an apply { } block.
I have a:

```
private suspend fun retrieve(accountAction: AccountAction): Any

suspend fun login() {  
 accountEvent.apply {  
  retrieve(it)
}
```

I tried to surround it with `suspend { retrieve(it) }`  `runblocking { retrieve(it) }` but it seems that even if it’s not generating an error (Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body) the code is not getting inside the retrieve function, but just passes through it and that’s why my unit tests fails.

FYI: this is a class, not an activity or a fragment.

Edit:

This is the actual code (from comment):

```
override suspend fun login(webView: WebView) = trackingId()       
    .flatMap { id -> AccountAction(client, id, WeakReference(webView), upgradeAccount) }
    .map {
        it.apply {       
            upgradeWebViewProgress(webView)
            suspend { retrieve(it) }  
        }
    }       
   .flatMap { updateAuth(it) }
```

Comment: I tried your code, filling out the parts you didn't provide, and it worked fine for me. Suspending inside `apply` works fine because it's an inline function. Can you please provide a minimal, but complete example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I deleted my answer as it did not help in your case (as @marstran pointed out). Please provide a more detailed example so we can try finding a better solution.

Comment: This is the main code. 

`override suspend fun login(webView: WebView) = trackingId()  
    .flatMap { id ->  
AccountAction(client, id, WeakReference(webView), upgradeAccount) 
}.map {  
  it.apply {  
    upgradeWebViewProgress(webView)  
    suspend { retrieve(it) }  }  
    }  
    .flatMap { updateAuth(it) }`

Comment: When I mock the return of retrieve fun in my unit tests. I get a value as if the retrieve fun never fired.

Comment: How about reordering your function like: `fun login(webView: WebView) { val result = trackingId().flatMap { id -> AccountAction(client, id, WeakReference(webView), upgradeAccount) } upgradeWebViewProgress(webView) val retrieved = retrieve(result) return retrieved.{ updateAuth(it) } }`

Comment: So you do the `flatMap` operation first, then upgrade your WebViewProgress, call the suspend function with the value from `retrieved`, (you do not need the `map` then), and finally with the result from `retrieved` you call `flatMap` and return that result

Comment: just one more note: `suspend { ... }` creates a lambda, it does not invoke the block

Comment: @AdrianK You mean it’s not actually firing the retrieve to execute ? Unlike runBlocking { } for exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

This shows an alternative without using `map` as it is not really required in my opionion for this example (except you really wanna chain all your calls)

```kotlin
suspend fun login(webView: WebView) { 
  val result = trackingId().flatMap { id -> AccountAction(client, id, WeakReference(webView), upgradeAccount) } 
  
  upgradeWebViewProgress(webView) 

  return retrieve(result).flatMap { updateAuth(it) } }
```

Comment: Yes, I know. That’s mainly the problem here, but is there another way of doing it ?

Comment: Well you could do without `apply`. Why do you have to use `apply` in this case? What I see, if `accountEvent` is of type `AccountAction` you could call  `retrieve(accountEvent)`.

Comment: My exemple is not a 100% copy of the real code, but I'm actually getting the accountEvent from a map fun. which is the same case as the apply fun.

Comment: Do you mind showing the actuall implementation? Maybe then your problem gets clearer and we could find a better solution.

Comment: @ChristianB You can still suspend inside the original `apply`-function because it's an inline function.

Comment: @Ape04 Oh, the actually issue is inside a `map` function? Then you should use the Flow-API.

Comment: @marstran I also suspected that, But can’t figure a way to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Flow`-API when you want to do asynchronous (suspend) operations on a list of elements like this. You can read about that API here: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/

Probably the simplest way to get your example working is by converting your list to a `Flow`, performing the suspending operations, then converting back to a `List`. Like this:

```
override suspend fun login(webView: WebView) = trackingId()       
    .flatMap { id -> AccountAction(client, id, WeakReference(webView), upgradeAccount) }
    .asFlow()
    .map {
        it.apply {       
            upgradeWebViewProgress(webView)
            retrieve(it)
        }
    }
    .toList()
    .flatMap { updateAuth(it) }
```

Note that this might not be the most efficient, because it will perform the `retrieve`-operations sequentially. You can use other operators on `Flow` to perform the operations in parallel for example.

Comment: The AccountAction returns an Observable<AcountAction> and thus I can’t use the asFlow() fun. Or is there a way to convert from Observable to Flow ?

Comment: @Ape04 Use the kotlinx-coroutines-rxjava2 library for interop.

Comment: I've seen that library. However, I'm trying to remove the rxjava library here and replace it with coroutines, so adding another that uses it isn’t much of an improvement.

Comment: Then you should change the call that returns an Observable to return a Flow instead.

Comment: Yes, I think I will do that eventually. I will try and keep you updated